# Delocalized electron wavefunction for a set of finite potential wells

Tags: wavefunction, electrons, potential

I have to solve a problem using MATLAB where I have to plot the wavefunctions of the electron in a set of **10 finite potential wells** arranged adjacent to each other with the potential at the extreme ends of the set extending to infinity.

I wrote the code and then plotted the various wavefunctions of the set of wells.
I have got the eigen vector as a 250*250 matrix.

I want to get a general idea about my plots (whether they refer to delocalized or quasi-bound state or bound state etc.).

[image: Delocalized electron wavefunction?]

[image: First harmonic?]

[image: Delocalized electron wavefunction?]

[image: Quasi-bound electron wavefunction?]

**Can anyone tell me whether each of these plots look like the wavefunctions of a delocalized or a quasi-bound or a bound electron?**

I am just a beginner in this area and I apologize if I have made any mistakes.

edit : I have increased the simulation domain and now my eigenvector matrix is having a dimension of 1210*1210. I plotted the 50th column of the matrix and I am getting this plot:

[image: Delocalized state?]
Does the above plot look like the wavefunction of a delocalized electron wavefunction or that of a quasi-bound electron or that of a bound electron?

Comment: eigenenergies are not matrices…. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry. I meant Eigen vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you structure was sandwiched by two infinite potential barrier at both ends, therefore strictly speaking, they are all bond states.

If classified these states from the barrier height, you may look up their eigen energies. I will roughly classify them from their appearances.

The first one is a deeply bounded state. The eigen energy is near the bottom of the well, therefore the wave function looks like a repetition of a localized function in each well. The connection between them is very low.

The second one is a bond state with an eigen energy near the barrier energy, slightly bellow the energy barrier. The wave function composed of wave functions peaked in each well, and envelope with a function from the bond state from the two ends (infinite potential).

The third wave function is a bond state with eigen energy in mid of the well potential barrier. It has clearly local oscillating wave-function in each well, but also an envelope function of the bond state from both ends. The connection between each well is higher than the first one, but lower than the second one.

The forth wave function has an eigen energy above the potential barrier. The form of each well is barely observed. But still the wells contribute to the fast oscillation of the wave function, enveloping with the slow variant function of the bond state from both ends.

The final wave function has eigen energy much higher that the potential barrier. The oscillation from the well bottom is lost. This state observed the bottom as a line with the energy average between the well and the barrier. The oscillation comes from the phase variance of a bond state from both ends.

Comment: I have obtained the eigenvectors using [eig_val,eig_vec] = eig[Hamiltonian_matrix]. Using eig_vec, I have plotted all these waveforms. The eig_vec matrix in my case is a 250*250 matrix. So, I can plot the wavefunctions of the particle using plot(eig_vec( : ,number)), where 'number' is a variable, right? I meant to say that we plot each column of the eig_vec matrix for obtaining the wavefunction, right? The third plot that I have posted corresponds to 'number'=250 or the last column of the eig_vec. So, should it not be of higher energy? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is dependent on whether the results were sorted. If it is solved by QR method, the eigen values may not be sorted.  You had another output "eigen_val" (a vector), each entrance of the vector is an eigen value, the related eigen vector is the corresponding column in the "eig_vec" matrix. Go and check the last value in the vector "eig_val" for the third figure.

Comment: I am sure that the third figure is not the wave function of the highest eigen value. For the highest eigen value, its envelope function should show up many node points.

Comment: Please do a double check on your arrangement and the plots. The third figure cannot be the highest energy state.

Comment: No, that doesn't help.  I Notice that in the third figure, there are only 9  sets of oscillation functions.  Each group is located on the barrier site. One possible is the quasi-bond state in the high energy region. Something cannot be   comprehended easily.

Comment: But that also occurs in the first figure. Do you have 10 wells, or 9 wells?